# String.Format() doesn't work, but string.Format() does

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would not believe this if I wasn't seeing it with my own eyes.

```
string test = String.Format( "{0} test {1}", "Mark", 13 );
```

Results in a value of `"{0} test {1}"` for variable `test`

```
string test = string.Format( "{0} test {1}", "Mark", 13 );
```

Results in a value of `"Mark test 13"` for variable `test`

Whhhhahaaaaattt? This is Xamarin by the way. I am very baffled here. Visual Studio 8.0.4. I've assigned the value of `test` to a UI element, logged it to LogCat, and viewed it with the debugger. They all agree on the odd value.

Comment: is this in an Android project or a separate library?  Which version of Android/mono/.NET. etc?

Comment: String is part of the System namespace. If you don't have `using String;` at the top of your file, or if you don't use `System.String` fully qualified referenced, then likely the String you're using isn't actually System.String. In C#, you should pretty much never use String directly. Instead, use `string`.

Comment: Install ReSharper, its default rule is to use built-in types and then you won't see these problems again :) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Built_In_Type_Naming.html

Comment: Relevant: https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are targetting Android, your `String` class refers to `java.lang.String` (not `System.String`, which is aliased as `string` in .NET)

It has Format method, but different placeholders
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.Lang.String.Format/p/System.String/Java.Lang.Object%5B%5D/

For expected placeholders check for example:
https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Comment: Aha! Thanks! That's something I'm not used to yet in Xamarin.